# Multiplicity of a polynomial in positive characteristic

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, ac.commutative-algebra

Let $\mathbb K$ be a field of characteristic $p>0$.
Let $f\in\mathbb K[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ be a multivariate polynomial and let $q\in\mathbb K^n$. Is there a computational method to determine the multiplicity of $f$ at $q$ without explicitly computing with Gröbner bases of the powers of the defining ideal of $q$?

Comment: One way (how good computationally, this is, I do not know) is to change $x_i$'s to $x_i-q_i$ where $q=(q_i)$ and thus assume $q$ is the origin. Then the multiplicity is the least degree of $f$, that is, we can write $f=f_p+f_{p+1}+\cdots$ where $f_k$ is the homogeneous term of degree $k$ and $f_p\neq 0$. The the multiplicity is $p$.

Comment: Thank you. I was looking for a linear algebra method, like in characteristic 0 case, where it suffice to take partial derivatives. Is there some analogue in positive characteristic?

Comment: What is multiplicity? I understand it with respect to a divisor but not with respect to a point...

Comment: In positive characteristics, derivatives are often ill-behaved. For example, $x^p-y^{p+1}$ has multiplicity $p>0$, but its $p$th derivatives at the origin is zero.

Comment: So, is it just the degree of the first non-vanishing homogeneous component, when you write $f$ as a polynomial in $y_k= x_k-q_k$? Why on Earth do you need the Grobner basis in this case? It  looks like a straightforward change of variable calculation,,,,

Comment: BTW, $p$-th derivativie is always zero in characteristic $p$ :-)) You oughta use divided powers derivatives!

Comment: Can you elaborate more on "divided powers derivatives"?